# Finding a point on a line where a line segment subtends maximum angle.

Tags: geometry

We have two fixed points A and B, and a line L. P is a variable point on the line L.

How do we find P, such that the $\alpha $ is maximum? (A,B and L are fixed.)

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting question, whose solution I came to know yesterday. I'll post a self-answer in 2 days from now. You may favourite this question, or try yourself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The locus of points which "see" $AB$ under a fixed angle is the union of two arcs of circles, hence you just have to find the circle through $A$ and $B$ which is tangent to the given line. The tangency point is the answer. This is also known as [Regiomontanus' problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regiomontanus%27_angle_maximization_problem).

[image]

Comment: How on earth are you such a genius! Amazing!!

Comment: @JaideepKhare: it is just standard mathematical culture. An interesting sub-problem is how to find $P$ through straightedge and compass: in the diagram above I found the center of the $ABP$ circle by intersecting the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ with a parabola, but there are plenty of other interesting approaches.

Comment: For instance: draw some circle $\Gamma$ through $A$ and $B$. Let $X=AB\cap \ell$ and let $\tau$ be a tangent to $\Gamma$ through $X$. If $Y=\tau\cap\Gamma$, the circle centered at $X$ through $Y$ meets $\ell$ at $P$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Figure 11]

I thing
IF $R_1 >R_2$ then $\angle AP_1B < \angle AP_2B$.
So  the point $P$ can be contruction below
[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 0):

for the given line we take the $x$ axes, then we get by the theorem of cosines
$$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{PB^2+PA^2-AB^2}{2PB\cdot PA}$$
and for the coordinates of $$A(a_x,a_y),B(b_x,b_y)$$ and $$P(x,0)$$
can you finish?